# Is there a way to remove an objects reflection in eevee render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, reflection

I'm using blender 2.92, is there a way to remove an object's reflection in eevee render? As you can see, the WINDOW of my model is color white, however I don't want it to reflect its color to the others parts of my train (like the area incircled in color red. Can someone help me?
[image]

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Comment: sorry, but it seems mine has an error when uploading blend files here. The upload keeps on stopping around near the end.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the screen space reflection? because it looks like you have. If it is the try disabling it . It might work
.By the way you can disable it in the render properties(located in the properties tab)>

Comment: I tried that before, it doesn't really help that much.

Comment: because it removes some important details.

Comment: Great, you solved my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It may not be right for your scene, but you can make a material invisible to reflections in EEVEE, as below. The nodes for the yellow emissive material are shown.

[image]

Unhecking 'Show Backface' in the material options prevents the back face from appearing to be overlaid on the object. Not sure why that's necessary, but it seems to be.

Comment: It doesn't work, even changing the materials settings

Comment: That's strange, I wonder what the gotcha is.. could you share a toy version of the failure on https://pasteall.org/blend/ ?